# type mismatch in the inner for loop in the variable s1 and s2

Tags: java

```
public static void printsubset(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> s) {
    for(ArrayList s1 : s) {
        for(Integer s2 : s1) {
            System.out.println(s2);
        }
    }
}
```

in the inner for loop i am getting type mismatch.s1 is of the type object .how do i convert it arraylist

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify in the first for each loop that s1 is an `ArrayList<Integer>` not just an `ArrayList` (which would imply an `ArrayList` of `Object`s.

```
public static void printsubset(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> s) {
    for(ArrayList<Integer> s1 : s) {
        for(Integer s2 : s1) {
            System.out.println(s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but that i have already defined it while initialising.is it not enough?@NESPowerGlove.Anyways thanks it works

Comment: You must also specify in loop otherwise all it knows is it is getting an `arraylist<Object>` for all it knows it could be `String` `Integer` `Double`

Comment: @bro05 thanks for making me understanding this logic